# Windows Phone as a game controller

Tags: windows-phone-8, tcp, accelerometer

I want to develop a application on Windows Phonw 8 that allows me to use the phone as a remote control for desktop. My application is runnning like this: the phone is a client that connects to a TCP/IP server, that is located on the PC. The client sends to server the data from accelerometer. I want to know how could i use this data to make my device something like a gamepad, to control a game. Is a way that i could do this? Could you give me some information, or what i need to study? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just answered your own question. If you make the TCP connection to the machine, you are free to send any data from the phone to the target computer. And if you wrote that game yourself, you can control it.

However, if you want to play *any* game with your phone, you will have to write your own windows driver and that is not something trivial.

Read more [Touch, Input, and HID: Architecture and Driver Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487435.aspx)